# finding all the records where associated records have a specific attribute value only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have two models `Product` and `Payment` with a `has_many` association.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments
end
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

`Payment` model has an attribute `paid` which can be `true` or `false`. How can i find all the `products` which have only `payments` with `paid` attribute set to `false`?

I tried:

```
Product.joins(:payments).where(payments: { paid: false }).distinct
```

but it returns the `products` where at least one `payment` is `false` when I need all of them to be `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a big fan of the [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem which simplifies a lot of queries with `ActiveRecord`

You are looking for products where there are only payments of false so you can add two clauses in your ransack query to achieve your desired result.

First install ransack and then use this to see if you get your desired result

```
Product.ransack(
  payments_paid_eq: false, 
  payments_paid_not_eq: true)
.result
.distinct
```

This is a slightly confusing query in some ways but in essence you are saying return all products with payments false and don't return ones with payment true.

An alternative approach without using the ransack gem would be the following

```
Product.joins(:payments)
  .where(payments: {paid: false})
  .where.not(payments: {paid: true})
  .distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this *might* do what you're looking for:

```
Product.
  where(id: Payment.where(paid: false).pluck(:product_id)).
  where.not(id: Payment.where(paid: true).pluck(:product_id))
```

Comment: Prefer `select` over `pluck` here, to use subqueries instead of pushing big lists of IDs around.

Comment: @matthewd You mean like `Payment.where(paid: false).select(:product_id)`?

Comment: yeah, exactly so.

Comment: @matthewd - I always get confused about `select` v `pluck`. I was under the impression that `select` instantiates the `Payment` records whereas `pluck` does not. In this case, that doesn't happen? Still so much to learn.

Comment: `select` returns a [deferred] Relation; `pluck` runs the query and returns an Array. If we were looping over the result, then pluck would be more efficient -- but as we're passing it back as a query condition, the still-not-executed Relation can be handled more efficiently.

Comment: That's a great explanation! Thanks for the time. (Storing that away in my addled brain.)